# Embed SWF in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

i want to embed swf into javascript, i know there is a method to do this, but how do i do it? here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
adroll_adv_id = "JD5ZGBNO4RBYVAMMMPX3J7";
adroll_pix_id = "CEJOJM5N5VAHBKCVMT2DML";
(function () {
var oldonload = window.onload;
window.onload = function(){
__adroll_loaded=true;
var scr = document.createElement("script");
var host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://s.adroll.com" : "http://a.adroll.com");
scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
scr.type = "text/javascript";
scr.src = host + "/j/roundtrip.js";
((document.getElementsByTagName('head') || [null])[0] ||
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode).appendChild(scr);
if(oldonload){oldonload()}};
}());
</script>
```

I have a flash banner actually, and i want to call this javascript into that banner

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call **javascript** function from flash, then you need to call like this from your flash code,

**Externalnterface.call("function_name","arg");**

You need to import the library **flash.external.ExternalInterface**;